# What's the C++ substitution of tuple enum variants present in Rust?

Tags: c++, rust, enums, tuples, ffi

I'm currently learning FFI between Rust and C++ and I would like to know how I can reimplement this enum ->

```rs
pub enum Stmt {
    Block(BlockStmt),
    Empty(EmptyStmt),
    Debugger(DebuggerStmt),
    With(WithStmt),
    Return(ReturnStmt),
    Labeled(LabeledStmt),
    Break(BreakStmt),
    Continue(ContinueStmt),
    If(IfStmt),
    Switch(SwitchStmt),
    Throw(ThrowStmt),
    Try(TryStmt),
    While(WhileStmt),
    DoWhile(DoWhileStmt),
    For(ForStmt),
    ForIn(ForInStmt),
    ForOf(ForOfStmt),
    Decl(Decl),
    Expr(ExprStmt),
}
```

in C++, since I wanted to transfer an enum variant of this enum across C++ and Rust.

I've gotten a fieldless C++ enum ready, I'm clueless on how to implement the tuple fields now.

```cpp
enum Stmt
{
    If,
    Try,
    For,
    With,
    Decl,
    Expr,
    ForOf,
    ForIn,
    Block,
    Empty,
    Break,
    Throw,
    While,
    Switch,
    Return,
    DoWhile,
    Labeled,
    Debugger,
    Continue,
};
```

Thanks in advance -- Yush.

Comment: rust enum are not ffi compatible. you would have to "hand coded" enum feature of rust by using this enum C++ and an union C++ and make a rust code doing the compatibility conversion

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks! That should somewhat work out for me.

Answer (score 1):

From https://rust-lang.github.io/unsafe-code-guidelines/layout/enums.html:

If you tag your enum with `#[repr(C, u8)]`, the layout is defined as a tag variable of type `std::uint8_t` followed by a union of all the variant types:

```cpp
struct Stmt {
    // Order is important. "Block" is 0, "Empty" is 1, etc.
    enum : std::uint8_t {
        Block, Empty, Debugger // ...
    } tag;
    union {
        // Types of these are the variant members
        BlockStmt block;
        EmptyStmt empty;
        DebuggerStmt debugger;
        // ...
    };
};


// And you can convert to a std::variant like so
std::variant<BlockStmt, EmptyStmt, DebuggerStmt, ...>
convert(Stmt v) {
    switch (v.tag) {
        case Stmt::Block: return { std::move(v.block) };
        case Stmt::Empty: return { std::move(v.empty) };
        // ...
    }

}
```

(The `u8` can be swapped for any int type by changing the underlying type of the enum of `Stmt::tag`. If using `#[repr(C)]`, the underlying type should be `int`)

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I probably should've mentioned that this enum is from another crate and not written by me

Comment: @yushie Without the `repr` tag, it doesn't have a defined C layout. You can copy it to a type that does

Comment: I would emphases that again none of this "C layout FFI" is mandatory by any line of C standard or C++ standard and that like rustc, a valid C compiler is allow to do anything about layout (except order). Thus in most case it's will work, do not complain if this doesn't work and allow a security bug.